# Passing variable values to and from an inside iframe

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe

I have a script in the iframe html file, and one in the main html file. I guess I can give names to these scripts if needed (its seems you can give names to everything).

I am trying to pass variable values to and from the main html file and the iframe.

So in the main file I wrote :

```
<script>
var test2 = 21;
document.getElementById("bottom1").innerHTML=test2;
</script>
```

This functions, it displays 21.

I have a button :

```
<div class="button" id="button" align="center">
<form>
  <input type="button" value="New" onclick="clearValues(); return false;">
  </input>
</form>
</div>
```

I have a function :

```
function clearValues() {
  window.frames['middle'].test = test2;
  document.getElementById('middle').contentWindow.location.reload();
  }
```

In the frame, I have :

```
<script id="here">
... Some stuff ...
var test;
document.getElementById("up1").innerHTML=test;
</script>
```

This functions, it displays "undefined". But when I click the button, it still displays "undefined" instead of 21. I guess the variable "test" gets redefined when the iframe is reloaded.

But how to avoid that beats me.

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to offer a clever suggestion, so I'll use cookies. Global variables names and values are going to be stored in a cookie. KISS (= "Keep It Simple and Supid").

Then I can have 2 functions, one which returns the value of the variable given its name and one which sets it.

If later on someone has a better idea, I would be very interested to read it.